# Adding parameter to sqldatasource, How should i pass them to execute my stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, gridview, sqldatasource

I am using a gridview where i am calling a stored procedure which has 4 input parameters.

Out of these 4 parameters, values are to be given such that

**DomainId** = This has to be the row which is to be deleted. This is a primary key

**Domain**   = This field has to be passed to SP as NULL.

**Description**= This field has to be passed as NULL.

**OperationType**= This field has to be passed by programmer as some static value say 4

How to i need to specify these here...

> More details of the Question are
>   [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363973/how-to-delete-data-from-gridview-which-is-using-datasource-and-sp-using-wizard).

Please help me out.

```
<DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="DomainId" 
                            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Size="4" Type="Int32" />  
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="Domain"  Size="16" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="Description" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="4" Name="OperationType" Type="Byte" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
```

On running my code using this

I gets an **error**

> Procedure or Function
>   'spOnlineTest_Domain' expects
>   parameter '@Domain', which was not
>   supplied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need to prefix your parameter name with a "@"

your parameters would look like this instead.

```
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="@Domain"  Size="16" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="@Description" Type="String" />
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="4" Name="@OperationType" Type="Byte" />
```

Comment: If you are passing in null for those two parameters (@Domain, @Description), try removing the @Domain and @Description parameters.